# Flutter AlertDialog only partly scrollable

Tags: flutter, flutter-dialog

I am struggling with an AlertDialog. It looks the way it should and the basic functions also work the way they should, but the scrolling behavior is strange.

The code looks like this:

```
  void openDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context, 
      builder: (context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, setState) => AlertDialog(
              content: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[

                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Field1"),
                      ),

                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Field2"),
                      ),

                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Field3"),
                      ),

                      TextFormField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Field4"),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          selectedImages = [];
                          await pickImages();
                          setState(() => selectedImages = selectedImages,);
                        },
                        child: const Text('Add images'),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        prompt,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          fontSize: 14
                        ),
                      ),

                      Visibility(
                        visible: selectedImages.isNotEmpty,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: selectedImages.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        
                            TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
                            imageControllers.add(controller);
                        
                            return Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [

                                Image.file(
                                  File(selectedImages[index].path),
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 100, 
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover, 
                                ),

                                TextFormField(
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Image label"),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      ]),
                ),
              ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context);
                    child: const Text("Add"),
                  ),
            )
          )
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

I've tried to clean it up and keep only what is necessary to run it - hope that worked.

Now this generates a scrollable AlterDialog. However, when I add pictures and they are shown underneath the rest of the dialog such that the dialog becomes too large to fit onto the screen, I can scroll the dialog, but onyl when I put my finger on the upper part of the dialog i.e., the textformfields above the elevated button. If I try to scroll further down it appears as if it tries to scroll the listview of pictures instead of the dialog as a whole.

I have tried to switch up the order of the widgets such that the singlechildscrollview is wrapping the rest, but that did not help.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: try with single SingleChildScrollView. Right now, you have two and they are nested.

Comment: Thank you for noticing! I removed the inner one and nothing changed sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've understood, instead of having the add button as a child inside your `AlertDialog`, put it on the `actions` property of the dialog:

```
actions: [
  ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
    child: const Text("Add"),
  ),
]
```

So you don't have to worry about the user scrolling the list of images instead of the dialog itself to click the add button.
Also, as your `AlertDialog` content its just a `SingleChildScrollView`, you can just use the property `scrollable: true` in the `AlertDialog` and have the same effect.
If you don't want to move the add `Button`, you will need to use a container to limit the size of your `TextFormField` and also the `ListView.builder`. Hope it helps

Comment: This is not the problem, actually. I already have the button in the actions property and can access it where I am in the "scrolling".

I will try to put it differently: It seems as if the ListView puts itself in front of the dialog such that my gestures are handled by the listview instead of the parent i.e., the alertdialog as a whole.

Comment: I tested your code and changed the list of images to a list of container with the same size of the images, i had to add an container around the ListView to limit the size because was breaking the layout. The scroll behaviour from the listview and the dialog was normal, can you try do the same thing? putting a container around the listview to limit the size